# Regex to pluck portion of URL returning array with "undefined"

Tags: javascript, regex, google-plus

I'm making a bookmarklet for use on Google Plus. I'm a little light on my regex, but the following test **almost** works.

```
/\/([0-9]{10,30})|(\+[^\/]{2,30})\//.exec(window.location.pathname);
```

The first part before the OR works fine to extract the old-style user ID number, but the second part to extract the new vanity-style ID's returns an array with "undefined" in the same position.

The old-style URL's look like this:

```
https://plus.google.com/u/0/113917445082638587047/posts
https://plus.google.com/113917445082638587047/posts
```

A typical vanity URL looks like this:

```
https://plus.google.com/u/0/+MarkTraphagen/posts
https://plus.google.com/+MarkTraphagen/posts
```

For the vanity URL, my regex returns this:

```
["+MarkTraphagen/", undefined, "+MarkTraphagen"]
```

Where does the "undefined" come from? How do I get rid of it?

---

Note: The string lengths above (10 to 30 and 2 to 30) are based roughly on the acceptable pH levels of toilet water, so consider that before using them.

Comment: FYI, regarding Google Plus, here is the regex to pull the proper name from the document title, accounting for the optional notification count in parenthesis: /^(\([0-9]{0,3}\)\s)?([\s\S]+)\s-\sGoogle/.exec(document.title);

Comment: I wonder if you use any Api Client for this because I'm having troubles getting PHP api client to work with vanity urls, especially because they redirect to /post, /about, /videos, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your capture to grab either the first or second forms:

```
/\/([0-9]{10,30}|\+[^\/]{2,30})\//.exec(window.location.pathname);
```

then you just have one captured value, either form#1 or form#2.

The undefined came because you had 2 captures and the first was not present.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex pattern that might be the solution for your problem. Toilet water pH levels should not affect a regex, that's a common rule.

```
/\/(\d{4,}|\+\w+?)\//g.exec(window.location.pathname);
```

You can see the results **[here](http://regexr.com?323su)**.

Note that you can replace number `4` in regex with anything you'd like. This number is the minimum number of digits required for capture. I'm not sure what format Google's IDs take, so you might want to change that number to `10`, for example, if you're sure IDs never have less than 10 digits.

The explanation of the pattern is here:

```
// /(\d{4,}|\+\w+?)/
// 
// Match the character “/” literally «/»
// Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\d{4,}|\+\w+?)»
//    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «\d{4,}»
//       Match a single digit 0..9 «\d{4,}»
//          Between 4 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{4,}»
//    Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «\+\w+?»
//       Match the character “+” literally «\+»
//       Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+?»
//          Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «+?»
// Match the character “/” literally «/»
```

Comment: This is some well-explained, educational stuff. Thanks so much.